# eas build showing white screen after splash screen. It was working fine with expo build earlier

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, eas, expo-build

Is there any extra step which isnt mentioned in the expo docs. Im stuck since a week this the problem. Can anyone help?

Every step mentioned in the docs, finding sol on the internet.